# Undefined method for NilClass in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, console, ruby-on-rails-7

[image]
I've a model named "ListingInfo", whenever I try to generate new object from this model, it shows the "undefined method for nilclass". I'm unable to add its attributes other than id.
I've also tried "create" method but on running "ListingInfo.count.all", it still returns zero(please see second image for more clarity). Means, it is still not being saved to database.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the object. Using `ListingInfo.new` will only instantiate it but won't validate it or save it to the DB. Also you shouldn't pass a value on the id that's generated automatically from Rails.

Solutions:

**Use new and then save the object**

```
listing = ListingInfo.new
listing.save
```

**Use create**

```
ListingInfo.create
```

**ActiveRecord::Base [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)**

**create(attributes = nil) {|object| ...}**

> Creates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database,
> if validations pass. The resulting object is returned whether the
> object was saved successfully to the database or not.

**new(attributes = nil) {|self if block_given?| ...}**

> New objects can be instantiated as either empty (pass no construction
> parameter) or pre-set with attributes but not yet saved (pass a hash
> with key names matching the associated table column names). In both
> instances, valid attribute keys are determined by the column names of
> the associated table — hence you can‘t have attributes that aren‘t
> part of the table columns.

Comment: Thanks Christos for your valuable suggestion, but I regret to inform it still doesn't work the way expected... please have a look at my modified question...

Comment: @Fuaad It seems that Postgres isn't working on your environment are you sure everything is set up correctly. If you check on the logs after you run `ListingInfo.all` it returns an error on the connection adapter for Postgres same for `create`.

Comment: @Fuaad validation fails that's why you see ROLLBACK. I'm guessing you didn't create apartment with id 1. use `create!` and `save!` in the console so that validations would raise an error for you to see.